# Unramified primes of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to show the following:

**Theorem**: Let $K$ be a number field and and $L$ be the splitting field of a polynomial $f$ over $K$. If $f$ is separable modulo a prime $\lambda$ of $K$, then $L$ is unramified above $\lambda$.

This should follow from the following theorem:

**Theorem**: Let $L / K$ be a finite extension of number fields, and $B$ resp. $A$ the ring of integers of $L$ resp. $K$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $K$ and $p$ the prime number lying under $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $\alpha \in B$. Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, and let $\overline{f} = \overline{g_1}^{e_1} \cdots \overline{g_r}^{e_r}$ be the distinct irreducible factors of $f$ modulo $\mathfrak{p}$. If $p$ does not divide the order of $B / A[\alpha]$, then $\mathfrak{p}B = \mathfrak{P}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{P_r}^{e_r}$.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which aspect is confusing you here? Is it the fact that in the first theorem $f$ is not the minimal polynomial of $K$? Or is it the fact that $p$ must not divide the order of $B/A[\alpha]$? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Well actually, I have been told in an answer to another question I asked here, that the first theorem is true, for it follows from the second one. In fact, the whole statement is confusing me. I do not know how to prove that the prime below $\lambda$ actually divides $B / A [\alpha]$ and I do not see why $e_1 = ... = e_r = 1$ should hold.

Comment: The connection is that if $f$ is separable modulo $\lambda$, then by definition, it splits into distinct irreducible factors mod $\lambda$. Thus the $e_i$ are all one.

Comment: Here's an expository paper by Keith Conrad that proves this: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf

Comment: For all I see in the paper, it proves the second theorem, but not the first one.

Comment: I think that the argument should be the following one: the primes which ramify in a compositum of (relative) number fields $F$ and $M$ are exactly the primes which ramify in $F$ or in $M$. In your setting, if $f$ is separable modulo $\lambda$ then $\lambda$ is unramified in $K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is any root of $f$, by the second theorem you quoted. Now $L$ is the compositum of all the $K(\alpha)$'s, and the claim follows.

Comment: Yes, I think that might work. However, why does $p$ - if $p$ is the prime lying below $\lambda$ - not divide the order of the group $B / A[\alpha]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by reformulating the first theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $F = K(\alpha)$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. Suppose that $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $K$, and the $f(X)$ splits as a product of distinct irreducibles modulo $\mathfrak p$ (i.e. $f$ is separable mod $\mathfrak p$). Then $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in $F$.

Why is this the same thing? As the splitting field of $f$, $L$ is the compositum of the fields $K(\alpha_i)$ where the $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $f$. Each of these fields is isomorphic, so if $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in one of them, it is unramified in all of them, and hence it is unramfied in $L$.

Let $p$ be the rational prime lying under $\mathfrak p$.

---

### **Case 1:**  $p\nmid [\mathcal O_F:\mathcal O_K[\alpha]]$.

Here, we are in the case of the second theorem. By assumption, $$\overline f=\overline g_1\cdots\overline g_n\pmod {\mathfrak p}$$
where the $g_i$ are distinct, so $\mathfrak p\mathcal O_F$ splits as a product of distinct primes. Hence it is unramified.

---

### **Case 2:**  $p\mid [\mathcal O_F:\mathcal O_K[\alpha]]$.

In this case, the theorem does not apply directly as stated. However, the proof of the theorem shows that $\mathfrak p$ splits as a product of distinct primes in $\mathcal O_K[\alpha]$. If $\mathfrak P^2\mid \mathfrak p\mathcal O_F$ for some prime $\mathfrak P$ of $\mathcal O_L$, then, taking $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak P\cap\mathcal O_K[\alpha]$, we see that $\mathfrak q^2\mid \mathfrak p\mathcal O_K[\alpha]$, which does not happen.

Comment: Just one last question: Which book did you consult for the proof? I'd like to understand in detail what you wrote for Case 2.

Comment: The notes that SpamIAm posted give a well written proof of the theorem in the case where $K=\mathbb Q$, and the general proof is identical. The theorem is know as the Kummer-Dedekind theorem, and can be found in any textbook on algebraic number theory. The idea is to show that $\mathcal O_K[\alpha]/\mathfrak p \cong \mathbb F_\mathfrak p[T]/\overline f$.