# $p$ ramify in $\mathcal{O}_K$ means repeated root modulo $p$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I read that if $p$ ramifies in $K$ the splitting field of a polynomial $f$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, then $p\mathcal{O}_K$ has a repeated factor. How does this lead to that $f$ modulo $p$ has a repeated root?

Comment: Have you come across the Kummer Dedkind theorem? You should see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782313/unramified-primes-of-splitting-field).